# How to SSH into Azure Ubuntu 16x from Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: ubuntu

I created a Ubuntu 16.x VM on Azure and selected the userid/password option for authentication. I can logon to the VM using the in-browser CLI on Azure portal. However, when I tried to ssh from Windows Subsystem for Linux (Ubuntu) on my Windows 10 machine, I get

`ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`

tried `ssh` with `-v` option and get the following

```
ssh -v userid@xx.xxx.xx.xxx
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to xx.xxx.xx.xxx [xx.xxx.xx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/userid/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/userid/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/userid/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/userid/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/userid/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/userid/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/userid/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/userid/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Is it not possible to `ssh` from Ubuntu on Windows without using the `ssh` authentication?

Update:
Turns out `ssh` from within corporate environment is filtered. I was able to successfully `ssh` from home.

Comment: Did you register your public key with the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux Subsystem for Windows (ubuntu) command line you can do ssh just like any other linux. 
I use it all of the time. (The Linux subsystem for Windows made Windows 10 much better IMHO)
So do the same command but put a couple more v's on it

```
ssh -vvv userid@ipaddr
```

It looks like the server may only accept ssh with keys. Have you logged into this server before using username and password (besides Azure console)? Also paste the output of the Azure connection with -vv if possible.

Generally it will go through the ssh keys and look for a match (yours did look for match) and then you will get messages like this when it goes to the next step.

```
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

I don see this in your output. 
I think this should show with one -v but would like to see the detailed verbose output.